# Can not read Avro Files using PIG via piggybank.jar running in Azure HDInsight

Tags: azure, apache-pig, avro, azure-hdinsight

Trying to port some existing PIG scripts that run perfectly locally and on Hortonworks to HDInsights and I am getting a class not found error when trying to read Avro files via Pig's piggybank (piggybank is included in the HDInsight distribution).

Wonder if anyone else has got Avro to work in HDInsight to work or has a work around (.eg. copy which jar where?)

In more detail ... Tracing this down I ran PIG directly via remote terminal on the Azure HDInsight instance.

The error I see is: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseException

This is I think, the json-simple library at https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/

I have tried adding this to a few places in the HDInsight VM (and explicitly registering the library in PIG) and still get the error.

The error is simple to reproduce by RDP into the Hadoop command line prompt on the desktop of an HDinsight Azure instance:

Start PIG with details ...

```
c:\apps\dist\pig-0.11.0.1.3.1.0-06\bin>pig -verbose -warning
```

Enter any line using AvroStorage. E.g.

```
grunt> LocationRecordAvro = LOAD 'wasb:///testinput/20130901.avro' USING org.apache.pig.
piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage();
```

Get an exception ...

```
2013-11-21 16:27:53,732 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - ERROR 1200: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 1, column 21> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage' with arguments 'null'
2013-11-21 16:27:53,732 [main] ERROR org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt - Failed to parse: Pig script failed to parse:
<line 1, column 21> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage' with arguments 'null'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:
191)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.validateQuery(PigServer.java:1571)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer$Graph.registerQuery(PigServer.java:1544)
        at org.apache.pig.PigServer.registerQuery(PigServer.java:516)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.processPig(GruntParser.java:99
1)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.pigscript.parser.PigScriptParser.parse(PigScript
Parser.java:412)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.j
ava:194)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.GruntParser.parseStopOnError(GruntParser.j
ava:170)
        at org.apache.pig.tools.grunt.Grunt.run(Grunt.java:69)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:538)
        at org.apache.pig.Main.main(Main.java:157)
Caused by:
<line 1, column 21> pig script failed to validate: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage' with arguments 'null'
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuild
er.java:835)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.load_clause(LogicalPlanGen
erator.java:3236)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.op_clause(LogicalPlanGener
ator.java:1315)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.general_statement(LogicalP
lanGenerator.java:799)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.statement(LogicalPlanGener
ator.java:517)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanGenerator.query(LogicalPlanGenerator
.java:392)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.QueryParserDriver.parse(QueryParserDriver.java:
184)
        ... 10 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: could not instantiate 'org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage' with arguments 'null'
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.jav
a:618)
        at org.apache.pig.parser.LogicalPlanBuilder.buildLoadOp(LogicalPlanBuild
er.java:823)
        ... 16 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/json/simple/parser/ParseException

        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2404)
        at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2714)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:343)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at org.apache.pig.impl.PigContext.instantiateFuncFromSpec(PigContext.jav
a:588)
        ... 17 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.json.simple.parser.ParseExcepti
on
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
        ... 23 more

grunt>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting environment variables such as PIG_CLASSPATH is not recommended for now in HDInsight, since you don't have admin access to the head node to do so.

Instead, there are **two dimensions** of a workaround we can use with Pig+Avro in HDInsight

A. Put the Avro and JSON jars in **Windows Azure Storage Blobs**, and register them from there.

B. Additionally for Avro, make a **dummy empty class with a different name than Avro** and put into the Piggybank.

The class loader wasn’t finding the necessary dependencies, because Avro was already in the Piggybank it doesn't search the right places for the JSON dependency.

The details of this snag... I believe it is related to how Java loads classes using custom class loaders. The way Pig implements this REGISTER keyword is that it uses a custom class loader that adds search locations to include these custom jars, but in this case the piggybank jar that contains the AvroStorage class is already in the classpath so it didn’t use the custom class loader. The problem then is that when Pig tries to instantiate it and it needs more custom jars, it doesn’t use the custom class loader so it can’t find the needed classes.

**The workaround:** To work around this problem I created an empty class, MyAvroStroage, that just vacuously inherits from AvroStorage, and put it into its own little jar (it’s just 650 bytes). Then I put this with all its dependencies on WASB, register them and use MyAvroStorage instead of AvroStorage then everything works fine.

Possible Workaround:

**1. Copy to WASB** 
For Part A, Copy jars to WASB as "PigExtras" folder for example. In another it was these commands (your source locations will vary, and your destination locations will be your container and account). For Part B, point to the jar of the dummy code MyAvroStorage.jar to upload it as well…

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\files\MyAvroStorage.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/MyAvroStorage.jar
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal c:\apps\dist\pig-0.11.0.1.3.1.0-06\piggybank.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/piggybank.jar
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal c:\apps\dist\oozie-3.3.2.1.3.1.0-06\oozie-win-distro\share\lib\pig\avro-1.5.3.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/avro-1.5.3.jar
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\apps\dist\oozie-3.3.2.1.3.1.0-06\oozie-win-distro\share\lib\oozie\json-simple-1.1.jar wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/json-simple-1.1.jar
```

**2. Create a simple repro script,** myscript.pig, and put that on Windows Azure Storage Blob as well. You can register a whole folder I believe with *.jar wildcard syntax.

```
REGISTER wasb:///PigExtras/*.jar;
myset = load 'wasb:///example/data/test.avro' using MyAvroStorage();
dump myset
```

Then upload the .pig to WASB as well

```
hadoop fs -copyFromLocal C:\files\myscript.pig wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/myscript.pig
```

**3. Submit the job** to the cluster from a client:

```
$job = New-AzureHDInsightPigJobDefinition -File    wasb://container@account.blob.core.windows.net/PigExtras/myscript.pig
Start-AzureHDInsightJob -Cluster $clust.Name -Subscription $sub.SubscriptionId -JobDefinition $job -Certificate $sub.Certificate
```

Comment: Forgot to mention the code for the MyAvroStorage.class 

    import org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.avro.AvroStorage;
    
    public class MyAvroStorage
    extends AvroStorage
    {}

Answer (score 0):

Do as Jason suggests and copy the jars (piggybank, avro and json) to blob storage and register them in your pig script. However, you don't need to create a dummy class extending AvroStorage. Just Remote Desktop to head node and rename/delete C:\apps\dist\pig-0.11.0.1.3.2.0-05\piggybank.jar to make sure the pigscript loads the piggybank file on the blob storage.

Comment: I hope MS might fix this and either keep piggybank.jar and add the dependencies (or better for me) remove piggyback.jar and let users register if needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

The way I solved it is to register json-simple-1.1.jar in the pig script.